# My drop down value always showing initial value only if i select another value also keep on showing initial value in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

When I select to change dropdown value, it is not showing selected value. It keep on showing the initial value. Only how can I display selected value? 
My dropdown :
Jsp:

```
    <body onload="form1.submit();">
     <form name="form1" action="#" >
    <select id="ddl" name="ddl" onchange="submit();">
                                 <% while (res.next()){%>                              
                <option value="<%=res.getString("ID")%>"><%=res.getString("UserId")%><%}
String Per=request.getParameter("ddl");
 out.println(Per);%>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form is submitted on page load, then it will do so in a endless loop. Please don't do that. Here is some demonstration code using JSTL.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action="#" >
            <select id="ddl" name="ddl" onchange="submit();"> 
                <c:forEach items='1,2,3,4,5' var="current"> 
                    <option value="${current}" 
                    <c:if test="${current == param.ddl}">
                        selected
                    </c:if>
                    >${current}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </form>
        Selected value is ${param.ddl}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @rickz, can you please update with your to my code

Comment: Scriptlets are frowned on at this website. If I posted a scriptlet solution, then I would have my hand slapped. If you want to continue using a scriptlet, then copy the logic of my code. Move the per variable assignment up above your loop. Inside your loop, check for equality of res.getString("ID") to the per variable. If it is found, then print the selected attribute within that option tag.